# DateTime accepts null value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

In the web app I'm working on, the web app should be able to accept null `DateTime`values, because customers might be hesitant to give information about their Date of Birth. Of course, this won't be an easy task, because in C#, `DateTime` is not nullable.

```
DateTime rawBirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text);
fxTxn.BirthDate = rawBirthDate;
```

with that, I had to change my code to accept a null value:

```
DateTime? rawBirthDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBirthDate) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(txtBirthDate);
fxTxn.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rawBirthDate);
```

this code, in turn, returns `1/1/0001 12:00:00.000 AM`. However, MSSQL throws a `DateOutOfRangeException`, saying the date must be between 1/1/1753 and 12/31/9999.

I'm completely stuck in here. On my SQL table, I allowed the `BirthDate` column to accept null values. Question now is, how do I make C# consider null DateTime values? The end result would be that, if the Customer did not provide Date of Birth information, the system should still be able to save the record but the BirthDate column in the customer's record would still be NULL.

Comment: What is `fxTxn`? How do you insert/update the date value to the database?

Comment: As a side note, the error message indicates that the column is a [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx). If you're using SQL Server 2008 or later, you ought to instead be using `date` or `datetime2` - those types are more efficient and `datetime2` is better aligned with the .NET `DateTime` class.

Comment: `DateTime `is not nullable, but `DateTime?` is. Sorry, it's a simple task.

Comment: Do not use `Convert.ToDateTime(rawBirthDate)` to project your `DateTime?` onto a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is this: your column table should accept null for BirthDate (that's correct). In C#, make the variable rawBirthDate nullable.

Now, the condition you need to check is:

```
rawBirthDate.HasValue
```

If it's true, then insert the date in db.

If false, **do not insert anything** in the db (that's what 'allow null' means in SQL).

Comment: you written wrong condition, correct is if false then don't pass value to db.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari Correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you converting null value in datetime, if you define nullable variable then it can store null vaue. **Actually you need to define BirthDate property also nullable and store null value if user have not entered date** like

```
fxTxn.BirthDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBirthDate) ? null : DateTime.Parse(txtBirthDate);
```

In db you need to make that column to allow null value and check value of BirthDate like

```
if (fxTxn.BirthDate.HasValue)
{
   // pass value in db otherwise not
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> how do I make C# consider null DateTime values

Your value was null. The problem is that you converted it to a standard DateTime which is giving you the `DateTime.MinValue` (1/1/0001)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be in the code that actually inserts the value into database:

```
...
var valueToInsert = rawBirthDate ?? DBNull.Value;
...
```